# Event Hub Scaling for high throughput telemetry

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have a project requiring 1-2Mil devices emitting 4, 4k messages per second.  Any suggestion how to scale the event hub for this application?

Cheers, Evian

Comment: read this: https://www.quora.com/Can-someone-explain-scalability-in-web-development-to-me-in-terms-of-a-chat-system

Comment: Hi Evian, these kinds of question are considered Off topic for Stack overflow as they generate opinionated responses. Please see [our topic guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Quora might be a better place for such questions.

Answer (score 1):

EventHub uses Throughout Unit as its billing unit. Each Throughput Unit represents 1 MB/s ingress rate, and the max Throughout Units you could have on a single EventHub is 20TU, which is 20MB/s.

Since your devices emit 44K messages per second, it means a max-out TU Event Hub might work for you if your message size is smaller than roughly 500 Byte. It should be noted that this is purely theoretical, while you should leave some buffer room on top of that.

If a single Event Hub won't work for you in terms of throughout, you could consider splitting your devices into groups (based on geographical location, for an example) and write to multiple eventhubs.